# Minimum drag/swipe distance with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm doing an HTML5 app, and I want to configure a swipe/drag function to open/close the offcanvas menu.

The function works great but I want to have more precise horizontal swipe or drag to prevent triggering vertical scroll and activating the menu.

By default swipe doesn't seem to works well because must be really fast (even changing the speed), drag works ok, but just pressing and move a bit activates the event.

I tried changing the variable `drag_lock_min_distance`, but unfortunately doesn't work at all, I cannot feel the difference even for the huge value that follows.

I tried checking real time the internal variables X speed and distance but they show the values taking as a reference the very first event, and not the `dragstart` and `dragend`.

I'm using raw hammer.js with twitter bootstrap, hammerjs version 1.0.6 from a CDN (last stable version). I'm testing on Android stock browser 4.1.2, and 4.4 (two different phones) as well as Google Chrome for Android.
Here you have the code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('contenido');
Hammer(element,{drag: true,
      prevent_default: false,
      drag_block_horizontal: true,
      drag_lock_min_distance: 250,
      hold: true,
      release: true}).on("dragleft", function(event) {
// function
});
Hammer(element,{drag: true,
      prevent_default: false,
      drag_block_horizontal: true,
      drag_lock_min_distance: 250,
      hold: true,
      release: true}).on("dragright", function(event) {
//function
});
```

Do you know any way to control the distance, to make firing of the event less sensible?

Comment: I added to the if statement the conditions && (event.gesture.deltaX>20)(right) and && (event.gesture.deltaX>(-20)))(left). It works better but still deltaX sometimes gives akward values. But for now is better than before. I'll be waiting for better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For someone coming across this in future, from Hammer `> 2.0`,

You can specify a *threshold* option to set the minimal distance required before recognizing, as shown below:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement, myOptions);
hammertime.get('swipe').set({ threshold: 100 });
hammertime.on('swipe', function(ev) {
   console.log(ev);
});
```

Comment: @Marcus the question is "The function works great but **I want to have more precise horizontal swipe or drag to prevent triggering vertical scroll** and activating the menu." and this is the solution for that. If you have different requirement please ask different question

Comment: yeah, that is true. I misread the OPs question. Thought we were asking the same initially.